# Can't figure out how to fix codeigniter's sessions not saved issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm using php 5.4.17RC1 moved from a server with php 5.3,
since then codeigniter's session aren't working (or working sometimes..)

I saw that there's a difference between the phpinfo on my old & new server which is:
Registered save handlers = files user (new server)
Registered save handlers = files user sqlite

Does anyone have a clue??

Thank you

Comment: I had the same thing happen a year ago. Never got it sorted. Even with core developers looking at it. We ended up just using `$_SESSION` straight up.

Comment: do you might can tell me which php version was it? tnx

Comment: I am not sure as I don't work there anymore. I *think* it was version 5.4 but it may have been 5.3. We were transitioning around that time, too, so I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making ajax requests if yes you need to know of the bug in some versions of codeigniter that destroys the session variable when ajax calls are made. You can solve this by overiding the default codeigniter session.